# stored procedure in informix

Tags: informix, proc

I tried to create a sample stored procedure in informix but it gives me a syntax error. Can any one say whats wrong with this?

```
drop procedure if exists sample(); 
create dba procedure sample() 
update employee set last_name="Tietz"  where emp_id = '2537';  
end procedure;
```

Thanks

Comment: In SQL avoid use of `"` string delimiter. Use standard `'`. Some databases including Informix works well with `"`, but it is not standard.

Comment: For me `emp_id` looks like `SERIAL` or other numeric filed. If it is numeric then you can simply use `emp_id = 2537;`

Comment: Thanks for the response.. 
`drop procedure if exists sample(); 
create dba procedure sample() 
  
end procedure;` 
and  
`update employee set last_name='Tietz'  where emp_id = '2537'; `

works fine separately but when combined, they are give me a syntax error. I am confused...

Comment: It really depends of tool/driver that you use to run such SQL. Some drivers are able to run many SQL statements at once, while others can run only one statement. I use Informix ODBC and JDBC drivers and they can run many statements at once. Your example works well with tools I use (I removed `IF EXISTS` because I use `IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 11.50.FC4`).

Answer (score 3):

The `IF EXISTS` clause is only available in very recent versions of Informix. I've got a couple of instances handy: 11.50.FC2 and 11.70.FC7. The statement `DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS foobar()` works on the later one only.

The rest of it looks OK to me.

Comment: Thanks for the response.. The problem is not with IF EXISTS..
`drop procedure if exists sample(); 
create dba procedure sample() 
  
end procedure;` 
and  
`update employee set last_name="Tietz"  where emp_id = '2537'; `

works fine separately but when combined, they are give me a syntax error. I am confused...

Comment: I copied and pasted your `CREATE DBA PROCEDURE ...` code into a session on one of my instances, and it created the procedure OK. Obviously I didn't try to run it, not having the underlying table. I'm assuming we're talking about an error at create-time, not in trying to invoke the procedure?